# Windows 11: Quick settings BT connect button not showing

Tags: bluetooth, windows-11

I used to use the quick settings menu alot for connecting my headphones if they didn't automaticly connect. However it has recently stopped appearing in this quick menu.
Currently the only way to connect is "Bluetooth & Devices > Devices > WH1000XM3: Connect".

I've tried removing the device and connecting it again, but I cant get it to remove the device.

I think all of this is verry wierd since this all used to work a month ago. Hope someone knows a fix :)